# Why does this imply normally distributed errors?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics

Why does the following process imply that the errors are normally distributed?

> A fellow researcher fits a simple linear regression model $Y_i = α + βX_i + U_i$ by least squares, but has
>   doubts that the standard assumption $E(U_i) = 0$ is correct for her data set. She decides to try 
>   test for this assumption by calculating the residuals from her regression $\hat{e}_i = Y_i - \hat{Y}_i$, and then
>   performing the usual $t$-test of the null hypothesis that their (population) mean is zero,

Comment: $U_i$ is an error term. $\hat{e}_i$ is a residual. Nothing stated here implies the errors are normally distributed. I assume where this text is going though is that the researcher will find $\frac{1}{n} \sum_i \hat{e}_i = 0$ or something computationally indistinguishable from zero like 1e-15.

Comment: It does not imply normal residuals. For example, suppose that I use Monte Carlo simulation every second of a time series for a minute using a linear model let's say y=x. Then let us say I use a Student's-t distribution with 3 degrees of freedom to generate noise in the y direction. I then do my linear regression and discover that the residuals are Student's-t. Am I surprised? I think not.

Comment: I have edited the question so it's text rather than an image. This is better for searching and also makes it readable for the vision-impaired (since various programs can read text out). Please identify the source of the quote. If it's a question for some subject you should also clearly state that fact (though I realize you're not asking us to solve the actual question being asked here -- I can find the full question online all over the place and it asks something else -- nevertheless you should be clear about it so people can avoid straying into answering the original question it asks)

Comment: Assuming the errors are normally distributed, is this proposal gonna work?

Comment: Did you miss what I said above? I've seen this question, it's been on the internet for years. You're asking me to do your work for you. Check the [help/on-topic] in relation to homework.

Comment: No, I searched online but I can only find one on Reddit, without any explanation. Could you share the link with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption of normality comes when applying the t-test - that assumes normality (though its type I error rate is not especially sensitive to normality).

Least squares is ML (and efficient) when you have iid normal errors but you can calculate least squares estimates without normality (they're still BLUE in the case of non-normality -- though that's not necessarily a particularly useful property if the distribution is so far from normal that all linear estimators of the coefficients are poor)

It's when you are deriving things like tests, confidence intervals and prediction intervals that you tend to make a distributional assumption, and you do make a normality assumption in deriving the t-test.

[It's not *necessary* to assume normality even then, but without assuming normality you will end up with some other test than the t-test, even if you use the same test statistic. Note further than normality isn't the only assumption involved in this.]

Comment: Assuming the errors are normally distributed, is this proposal gonna work?

Comment: *Now* you're asking me to do the assignment.